# Woocommerce CSV Product Import - Stop Attributes Automatically being "used for Variations"

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I have a shop that has around 4000 different products, split over lots of different attributes. However, i'd like to add attributes to these products using a csv import -without- the attributes themselves being used to create more variations.

During my experimentation, i found that any new attributes i added to the header of the csv, [as mentioned in the official schema documents](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Product-CSV-Import-Schema) will automatically tick the "Used for variations" box. I'm looking for a way for this to -not- happen. There's no mention of it on their documentation. Would the best way be to create a custom column and adjust the importers logic based on that field? Or is there something more obvious that i'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

In the parent product import (the one that has type "variable")
set the Attribute 1 global column to 1

In the child product import (the one that has type "variant")
set the Attribute 1 name column to the name of the attribute

It will not use it for variants.

---

For people who want their import to be a variant

In the parent product import (the one that has type "variable")
set the Attribute 1 global column to 1

In the child product import (the one that has type "variant")
set the Attribute 1 name column to the name of the attribute **with pa_ in front of it** for example size should be "pa_size"